# jQuery not keeping track of validation errors correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a small jQuery/AJAX script that checks if a username is already in use or not. It queries a PHP script, which in turn outputs the number of users with the specified username. I have an error counter that keeps track of the number of validation errors on the form, and I increment the counter if the username is already in use.

```
//Keep track of number of errors
 var errors = 0;
 //Keep track of error messages
 var errorMsg = "";

//Check if the passwords match (this part works as expected)
 if($("#password").val() != $("#repeat").val()) {
     errors++;
     errorMsg += "<li>Passwords do not match!</li>";
 }

     //Now check if the user exists
     var userName = $("#user").val();
    $.ajax({   
        type: "POST",
        data : {'user': userName},
        cache: false,  
        url: "js/ajax/addUser.php?action=checkuser",   
        success: function(data){
            var result = parseInt(data);
            //For debugging purposes
            alert("Before checking the data, # of errors is: " + errors);
            if(result > 0) {
                errors++;
                errorMsg += "<li>A user with the name <strong>" + userName + "</strong> already exists!</li>";
            }
            //For debugging purposes
            alert("After checking the data, # of errors is: " + errors);

        }
    });
    //For debugging purposes
    alert("Before validating the form, # of errors is: " + errors);

     if(errors > 0) {
         //Output error message
     }
     else {
         //Send the form
     }
```

As mentioned in the comments, I have a few `alert()`'s for debugging. The first two (within the AJAX request) display the correct amount of errors. However, when I get to the third one, it completely disregards any errors that occurred within the AJAX request.

I have trimmed my code down to just the essentials, but if the error is not clear within the snippet provided, I can post the entire thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ajax is asynchronous.  Place your logic inside the success.

```
//Keep track of number of errors
 var errors = 0;
 //Keep track of error messages
 var errorMsg = "";

//Check if the passwords match (this part works as expected)
 if($("#password").val() != $("#repeat").val()) {
     errors++;
     errorMsg += "<li>Passwords do not match!</li>";
 }

     //Now check if the user exists
     var userName = $("#user").val();
    $.ajax({   
        type: "POST",
        data : {'user': userName},
        cache: false,  
        url: "js/ajax/addUser.php?action=checkuser",   
        success: function(data){
            var result = parseInt(data);
            //For debugging purposes
            alert("Before checking the data, # of errors is: " + errors);
            if(result > 0) {
                errors++;
                errorMsg += "<li>A user with the name <strong>" + userName + "</strong> already exists!</li>";
            }
            //For debugging purposes
            alert("After checking the data, # of errors is: " + errors);

            if(errors > 0) {
                //Output error message
            }
            else {
                //Send the form
            }
        }
    });
    //For debugging purposes
    alert("Before validating the form, # of errors is: " + errors);
```

Answer (score 2):

The callback function for the ajax request is executed Asynchronously. Therefore the code that is immediately after this request will likely execute before the call returns.

Comment: "will likely execute" - if it's set to asynchronous, the code after `$.ajax` is guaranteed to execute before the callback.

Comment: Someone could have overridden the alert or the $.ajax functions and changed their function :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem as I understand with this is the way AJAX call is being made. The third alert

```
alert("Before validating the form, # of errors is: " + errors);
```

is called simultaneously along with the  $.ajax call you made.

As your intent is to invoke the calls synchronously, you might want to chain the calls using jquery [Deffered Object](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/)

If you are looking for a solution in your current code, you need to move the below code inside the success handler.

```
alert("Before validating the form, # of errors is: " + errors);

     if(errors > 0) {
         //Output error message
     }
     else {
         //Send the form
     }
```

Comment: Didn't realize there were already two answers saying the same thing I've mentioned!

Answer (score 0):

you can add **async:false** to your function and everything will work for you .

```
type: "POST",
async:false
```